# Why was my answer flagged?

Tags: discussion

My answer here [Can Mystique replicate a person by just looking at a photograph?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80559/can-mystique-replicate-a-person-by-just-looking-at-a-photograph/95423#95423) flagged as

> Some of the information contained in this post requires additional references. Please edit to add citations to reliable sources that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or deleted.

Just because a mod disagrees with my answer does not mean it lacks citations. As noted, it occurred on screen in **First Class**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the record, I don't want you to feel that I personally *dislike* this answer. It was user-flagged as "not an answer" (which I disputed) and nominated for deletion as being "low quality" which I also felt was unfair.

### With regard to the moderator notice

You've made some very bold assertions in this short answer. I felt that additional citations (specifically something that confirms that this is specifically intended to be an in-universe reference to the earlier film rather than an out-of-universe wink at the audience) would improve this answer immeasurably.

Comment: I do accept that my original comment wording was poorly chosen; *"Since the choice of actors is an out of universe decision, this doesn't answer the question in any meaningful sense"*. I've [amended it](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80559/can-mystique-replicate-a-person-by-just-looking-at-a-photograph/95423#comment217253_95423) to make it a bit less confronting.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're a great contributor to the site, cde, and I enjoy seeing your answers, but you have a tendency to leave very brief answers, and very brief answers tend to get flagged and/or deleted.

Some questions only require a few lines of text to answer them, but most of the time, the longer an answer is, the better it is, and the more votes it will receive.  This is one place where being brief and to the point isn't necessarily a good thing.  Longer answers suggest that more thought went into them.  A short answer suggests that the user may have been in a rush and didn't put much effort into it.

I'm not saying that you are posting half assed answers - you aren't.  I'm just saying that some users might interpret short answers that way.  There is also the possibility that people might think you're trying to be The Fastest Gun In The West  - plopping down a very curt answer and moving along to the next one.

It appears that in this case, a mod didn't flag your answer - a regular user did - and the mod was simply trying to help you improve the answer.  I also think there was a bit of confusion about the thrust of your argument, which could have been avoided if the answer wasn't so short.

I hope you don't think I'm trashing you or criticizing your contributions, because I'm definitely not:  I enjoy seeing you around the site and I think you post some great answers.  I'm simply trying to help you avoid the repetition of this problem in the future.

(And by the way, the answer as it now stands is great - you have my +1)